# How do I concatenation two strings in Bash without using variables?

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

I'm trying to tar a large directory, and I'd like the output file to contain the date. Here's what I have so far.

```
tar -zcvf "mywebsite website backup" $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T") public_html
```

This doesn't quite work though. As an example, I'm trying to get the single string below to be the file name. The call to date is working fine and I don't need help with that, but I'm not sure how to concatenate the "my website backup" with the output from date without first storing them in variables (which seems ham fisted).

```
mywebsite website backup 2001-12-01 12:04:03
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables and such are interpreted within double quotes (but not within single quotes):

```
tar -zcvf "mywebsite website backup $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T').tgz" public_html
```

(I added the `.tgz` suffix, you apparently forgot.)

If you had no white space in your file name, you could do it without quotes:

```
tar -zcvf foo_backup_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%T').tgz foo/
```

Or you could turn it around and use the fact that `date` already accepts a format string:

```
tar -zcvf $(date +'foo_backup_%Y-%m-%d_%T.tgz') foo/
```

(Still needs double quotes around `$()` if the file name contains white space.)

NB: For various reasons it is usually not a good idea to include colons in file names.

Comment: I tried the command you listed and it threw this error. Just incase this wasn't clear $(date) is a call to the date command, not a variable.                                                                      tar (child): Cannot connect to mywebsite website backup 2012-02-05 09: resolve failed

Comment: @Jazzepi: The colon might present a problem with your setup (seems to be interpreted as network path). Use another time format. This has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Yeah that seems to have been the problem. I didn't realize you could do $() calls inside of a string literal.

Comment: @Jazzepi: Your last comment doesn't make much sense, since you already used `$()` in a "string literal" in your original question. Quotes are not necessary to make somthing a literal in bash. (Also, accepting my answer would be nice, if it did help you.)

Comment: I didn't, actually. I used $() to interpret a command to, I guess, what is another instance of Bash that gets spawned off to run what's inside of $() before returning the results. Inside of that I used a string literal, but I wasn't using $() inside of a string literal. I accepted the answer, but you can't do that until some amount of time passes after you post it.

Comment: @Jazzepi: double-quotes don't make a string literal in bash; in fact, most things are string literals by default.  For example in `echo foo bar`, `foo` and `bar` are string literals.  That's what @hop meant by saying you'd already used `$()` inside a string literal.  What double-quotes actually do is prevent some types of interpretation (e.g. spaces as "word" breaks) but allow others (e.g. `$var`, `$(cmd)`).  Single-quotes, on the other hand, prevent almost all types of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try syntax:

```
tar -zcvf "mywebsite website backup `date \"+%Y-%m-%d %T\"`.tgz" public_html
```

Comment: backticks are deprecated in favor of `$()`. using single quotes for the format string would make escaping unnecessary.